# Searching a column in Entity Framework with multiple values

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to run a search on one particular field of a table with a list of values. Not able to find a solution so far. Any help is really appreciated.

Here is the scenario

```
var records = new PagedList<Required>();
var result = db.Required.Where(x => filter == null || (x.Title.Contains(filter)) || x.CID.Contains(filter));

foreach (string str in SelectedNetwork)
                {
                    string tempStr = str;

                    result = result.Where(x => x.Network == tempStr);
                    records.TotalRecords = result.Count();
                }

records.Content = result
                        .Where(x => filter == null ||
                                (x.Title.Contains(filter))
                                   || x.CID.Contains(filter)
                              )
                        .OrderBy(sort + " " + sortdir)
                        .Skip((page - 1) * Convert.ToInt32(records.PageSize))
                        .Take(Convert.ToInt32(records.PageSize))
                        .ToList();
```

highlighted code in the foreach loop fails to run as per expectation. Is there any way, I can fix it?

Thanks
Tutumon

Comment: ....in this type of situation you must debug it ...so i advice you pit a break point on the foreach loop line...and work your way through the code and see whats being filtered ....and returned....from there we can move on...

Comment: Issue is not with the debugging. after the first iteration, the element result become the result of first filtration. So during second iteration, we are not searching on the actual source. Hence the second filtration become irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You must take into account that LINQ expressions are queries, until you materialize them. To materialize them you need to either enumerate them, or convert them to a list, array, or whatever, i.e. enumerate their members in a `foreach`, or call a method like `ToList()`, or `ToArray()`.

In your code the original query stored in result is not materialized, so everytime a `foreach` loop is executed, a new `Where` contidion is added to the original query. To vaoid this behavior you need to recreate the whole `results` query in each iteration, so that you get a fresh copy of the unfilterd expression.

There would be another solution which would be to materialize the result query and then run the `foreach` loop as is. The problem of this solution would be that you would get all the data from the database, keep it in memory and run the `Where` and the `Count` on the in-memory copy. Unless there is a very small number of rows in `Required` that would be a very bad idea.